# Firebase, save data by setValue function not working with inherited class

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making a simple android app using firebase database (9.0.2) to save data.

The app really simple, it have a button, when click on it we'll try to write an object to firebase database.

The object as below:

```
public class Place {
    public String name;
    public Address address;
}
```

and

```
public class Shop extends Place {
    public General generalInfo;
    public Details detailsInfo;
}
```

I create a Shop object then use setValue function to save it to firebase database.

Check it on Firebase console, the data was added, but it missing name, address fields.

Did you face it before? What can i do in this case in order to make it work?

Comment: you need to show your code of saving part.

Comment: This is a known issue in the current SDK (9.0.2): properties/fields from ancestor classes are not serialized. I wrote an answer on this before, let me find it.